# Nodejs class that is self describing into a file

Tags: node.js

Maybe this is basic stuff and things I want to do is really simple, but being a bit junior in Javascript I cannot find any answer to my issue.

What I want to achieve is that from code (in runtime) I want a file to be generated containing all properties and methods (including parameters and if possible return values) described.

Console logging `this.__proto__` and `Object.keys(this)` prints somewhat what I expect.
However, using the `Object.keys(this.__proto__)` does not return anything useable. I guess this is somehow connected to the fact that the `__proto__` contains functions, which are fx. not parsable with `JSON.parse()`.

Any ideas how to approach this?

Test code I used:

```
const fs = require('fs');

class Exporter {
    constructor(name) {
        this.filename = `./${name}.export`;
    }

    export(me) {
        let file = '';
        let d

        d = Object.keys(me);
        for (let i = 0; i < d.length; i++) { file += d[i] + '\n'; }
        d = Object.keys(me.__proto__);
        for (let i = 0; i < d.length; i++) { file += d[i] + '\n'; }


        fs.writeFileSync(this.filename, file);
    }
}

class Box {
    constructor(name, length, width, height) {
        this.name = name;
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this._export = new Exporter(this.name);

        this._export.export(this);
    }

    volume() {
        return this.length * this.height * this.width;
    }
}

myBox = new Box('Matts', 2, 3, 4); //creates file Matts.export

console.log(myBox.volume()); //prints '24'
```

File "Matts.export" written contains:

```
name
length
width
height
_export
```

So basically the `Objects.keys(me.__proto__)` returned a zero length array. I did expect the `volume` function stated. Preferably with parameters and return value. But I guess the later is hard to achieve in JavaScript.

Comment: Can you provide some example input and your desire output?

Comment: Edited the base post with the requested info! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because those properties are not enumerable, you can check by using `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors()`

```js
class Box {
    constructor(name, length, width, height) {
        this.name = name;
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    volume() {
        return this.length * this.height * this.width;
    }
}

let myBox = new Box("Matts",2,3,4);

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(myBox.__proto__));
```

However,`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors()` returns an object which have the same keys as the given object. So you can get the keys from the descriptors:

```js
class Box {
    constructor(name, length, width, height) {
        this.name = name;
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    volume() {
        return this.length * this.height * this.width;
    }
}

let myBox = new Box("Matts",2,3,4);

console.log(Object.keys(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(myBox.__proto__)));
```